# Draw LineChart separately using MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, json, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) Library to Display the LineChart .I am not Able to Distinctly Display the LineChart Seperately with TermWise.I have Used Same ArrayList i.e called allMarks to Store the information for all the Term.When i Clear the ArrayList then only the Specific Term Marks are plotted in the Chart, if ArrayList.Clear(); is not used then all the Marks are Displayed. How can each term marks be Seperately Displayed?

**Dashboard**

```
public class Dashboard extends Fragment {

    ListView listViewNotice, listviewpendingbills;
    String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/getNotices";
    String Navigation_URL_BIlls = "http://192.168.100.5:84/Api/financeApi/getAllFees";
    String Navigation_URL_CHART = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/getSingleStudentsMarks";
    String Navigation_URL_getExam = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/getExams";
    String Navigation_URL_getExamData = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/getStdMarksByTermStd";


    String access_token;
    String Notice, BillNumber, Status, AmountPaid, ReceiptIssueDate;
    String master_id;
    TextView pendingbills, NoNotice;
    LineChart chart;


    private static final String TAG = "Test";
    ArrayList<Entry> entries, entry;
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    LineDataSet set, set1;
    LineData data, data2;

    // ArrayList<LineData> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList allExams;
    ArrayList getCourses;
    ArrayList getMarks;
    ArrayList getCourseID;
    ArrayList getExamDesc;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        // getActivity().setTitle("St. Xavier's High School");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        listViewNotice = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_student_notice_dashboard);
        listviewpendingbills = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_pendingbills);
        pendingbills = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textpendingbills);
        NoNotice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textnoticedashboard);
        //  lineChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart1);
        chart = (LineChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart1);

        SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(getContext());
        session.checkLogin();
        access_token = session.getAccesstToken();
        master_id = session.getMasterId();
        makeJsonObjectRequestNotices();
        makeJsonObjectRequestBills();
        //  makeJsonObjectRequestGraph();

        makeJsonObjectMarksWithGraph();

        allExams = new ArrayList();
        getCourses = new ArrayList();
        getMarks = new ArrayList();
        getCourseID = new ArrayList();
        getExamDesc = new ArrayList();
        labels.add("Math");
        chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
        chart.invalidate();

        return view;
    }

  String examDescription;
    private void makeJsonObjectMarksWithGraph() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL1 = Navigation_URL_getExam;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL1,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String TermID = jsonObject.getString("TermID");
                                examDescription = jsonObject.getString("examDescription");
                                getTermID(TermID, examDescription);
                                allExams.add(TermID);
                                Log.d("Term ID", getTermID(TermID, examDescription));
                            }
                            Log.d("All Exam", String.valueOf(allExams.size()));
                            int j;
                            for (j = 0; j < allExams.size(); j++) {
                                String termID = (String) allExams.get(j);
                                getExamData(termID);
                            }


                            //Collections.sort(entries, new EntryXComparator());

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                , new Response.ErrorListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        )

        {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }

      /*      @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("id", master_id);
                //map.put("accessID", accessID);
                map.put("currentUser", master_id);
                return map;

            }   */
        };


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

 public String TermID;
    public String Description;

    private String getTermID(String TermID, String Description) {
        this.TermID = TermID;
        this.Description = Description;
        return TermID;
    }

    private void getExamData(String TermID) {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL1 = Navigation_URL_getExamData + "?StdID=" + master_id + "&TermID=" + TermID;
        //String URL1 = Navigation_URL_CHART + "?StdID=" + master_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL1,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            if (jArray.length() != 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                                    Log.d("JSON Object", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
                                    String CourseId = jsonObject.getString("CourseID");
                                    String CourseName = jsonObject.getString("CourseName");
                                    String examDescription = jsonObject.getString("examDescription");
                                    Float Marks = Float.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("Marks"));


                                    getMarks.add(Marks);
                                    getCourses.add(CourseName);
                                    getCourseID.add(CourseId);
                                    getExamDesc.add(examDescription);
                                    System.out.println("the Courses are" + getCourses);

                                }
                                Log.d("JSON Object", String.valueOf(getMarks));
                                plotGraph(getMarks);
                                //getMarks.clear();

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
  ArrayList<Entry> allMarks = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    private void plotGraph(ArrayList getMarks) {
        ArrayList<Entry> allMarks = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        System.out.println("GetMARKS" + getMarks.size());
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> testDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        // HashMap<ILineDataSet> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


        for (int k = 0; k < getMarks.size(); k++) {
          /*  allMarks.add(new Entry(k, (Float) getMarks.get(k)));
            set = new LineDataSet(allMarks, examDescription);
            data = new LineData(set);
            lines.add(data);

            chart.setData(data);

            set.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            set.setDrawFilled(true);
            set.setDrawValues(true);
            chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            chart.invalidate();

            */


            allMarks.add(new Entry(k, (Float) getMarks.get(k)));
            LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(allMarks, examDescription);
            // set different color for each set as your requirement
            testDataSet.add(set);
            chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            chart.invalidate();
            //  allMarks.clear();

        }

        chart.setData(new LineData(testDataSet));
    }
}
```

**http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/getSingleStudentsMarks?StdID=0095**

```
[
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 4027,
    "Marks": 45,
    "Sno": 2107,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 6022,
    "CourseName": "Arts",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "First Term",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 5034,
    "Marks": 90,
    "Sno": 2108,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 6022,
    "CourseName": "Math",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "First Term",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 5035,
    "Marks": 52,
    "Sno": 2109,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 6022,
    "CourseName": "English",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "First Term",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 6034,
    "Marks": 70,
    "Sno": 2110,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 6022,
    "CourseName": "hi",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "First Term",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 4027,
    "Marks": 50,
    "Sno": 4119,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7024,
    "CourseName": "Arts",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "Second",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 5034,
    "Marks": 60,
    "Sno": 4120,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7024,
    "CourseName": "Math",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "Second",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 5035,
    "Marks": 70,
    "Sno": 4121,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7024,
    "CourseName": "English",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "Second",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 6034,
    "Marks": 80,
    "Sno": 4122,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7024,
    "CourseName": "hi",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "Second",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 4027,
    "Marks": 10,
    "Sno": 4123,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7025,
    "CourseName": "Arts",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "Third",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 5034,
    "Marks": 20,
    "Sno": 4124,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7025,
    "CourseName": "Math",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "Third",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 5035,
    "Marks": 30,
    "Sno": 4125,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7025,
    "CourseName": "English",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "Third",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 6034,
    "Marks": 90,
    "Sno": 4126,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7025,
    "CourseName": "hi",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "Third",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 4027,
    "Marks": 80,
    "Sno": 4127,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7026,
    "CourseName": "Arts",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "fourth term",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 5034,
    "Marks": 10,
    "Sno": 4128,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7026,
    "CourseName": "Math",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "fourth term",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 5035,
    "Marks": 76,
    "Sno": 4129,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7026,
    "CourseName": "English",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "fourth term",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 6034,
    "Marks": 93,
    "Sno": 4130,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 7026,
    "CourseName": "hi",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "fourth term",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  }
]
```

> I am currently getting all the term marks in the OneArray Called as **AllMarks**. Can't I plot the marks with Different Term with Different Color in Same Chart?

Comment: see my answer hope this help you out.

Comment: `Can't i plot the marks with Different Term with Different Color in Same Chart` #Seon Sorry . I didn't try this . Used SINGLE . https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JJzRsidtitDEZ3oFrF1lxp4-BY0ZjFPhDF2XOlb_5MfWXsclVQDWnKB70i4wc8xsR6g=h900-rw

Comment: @intellijAmiya Till now i have assigned the termwise marks in singleArrayList.Is it possible that i can create the ArrayLIst numbe ralso Dynamic as the TermWise and Store the marks Differently and Plot it.

Comment: Looks like possible .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your work around..
The term data should be grouped and displayed

```
private void makeJsonObjectMarksWithGraph() {

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    String URL1 = Navigation_URL_getExam;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL1,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {


                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<JSONObject>> dataFilteredByTerm = new HashMap<>();

// filter response to add terms
    ArrayList<Integer> termIDs = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            termIDs.add(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optInt("TermID"));
        }
        boolean check = termIDs.contains(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("TermID"));
        if (check) {
            termIDs.add(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optInt("TermID"));
        }
    }
//group json response according to term ids
    for (int i = 0; i < termIDs.size(); i++) {

        ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray.length(); k++) {

            if (termIDs.get(i) == jsonArray.optJSONObject(k).optInt("TermID")) {

                jsonObjects.add(jsonArray.optJSONObject(k));
            }
        }

        dataFilteredByTerm.put(termIDs.get(i), jsonObjects);
    }
//set entry for every marks grouped by terms
    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> testDataSet = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataFilteredByTerm.size(); i++) {

        ArrayList<JSONObject> values = dataFilteredByTerm.get(termIDs.get(i));
        ArrayList<Entry> allMarks = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int k = 0; k < values.size(); k++) {
            allMarks.add(new Entry(k, values.get(k).optInt("Marks")));
        }
        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(allMarks, values.get(i).optString("examDescription"));

        testDataSet.add(set);

    }
    chart.setData(new LineData(testDataSet));
    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    chart.invalidate();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }


            }

            , new Response.ErrorListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    )

    {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headers;
        }

  /*      @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("id", master_id);
            //map.put("accessID", accessID);
            map.put("currentUser", master_id);
            return map;

        }   */
    };


    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Comment: I got stucked from a while.This code worked, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It will show your chart as a cubic shape not straight line.

```
dataset.setDrawFilled(true);
dataset.setDrawCubic(true);
dataset.setDrawValues(false);
```

dataset is the object of **LineDataSet**.

Above code works with version compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'

Comment: setDrawCubic(true); function is not recognized

Comment: Which version are you using? I am using 2.1.6

Comment: compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'.Same as previous result

Comment: Try this for your version lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);

Comment: The code i was posted it only change the curve of your linechart not more than it. For other you need to implement many things to looks like your actual output.

Comment: Same result .only changes on displaying

Comment: Can i store marks on arraylist for firstTerm ,plot it and clear arraylist and same work for other term

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148387/discussion-between-andy-developer-and-seon).